# How do I deploy flutter app on mobile device for testing without using play store

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, apk

I am new to flutter development. I have created a sample app (flutter 2.2 and VS Code) that uses google maps and device location tracking. I want to test this on field by deploying on to my mobile. Can I know the steps to achieve this with out publishing the app to play store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create apk for your app and try below commands

clean your project

> flutter clean

get packages

> flutter pub get

build your apk

> flutter build apk --release

find your apk in your machine

your project name\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk(on release mode)

copy this APK and install your mobile divice

refer [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSn68_WLRKc) video

Comment: Thanks Ravindra for your steps needed to follow to deploy the apk on the device.

Answer (score 1):

there is two options :

1. you can debug your phone (by activating developer options) and use it as emulator
2. or you can export the aplication by using this line of command in your terminal and install the apk in your phone :

   Flutter build apk

Comment: Second option is what I was looking for. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

`flutter install` from the command line works for me in the latest (3.13.4) Flutter to build and install to my Android device.

To be able to do this you have to have unlocked Developer options on your device and allowed USB debugging. Connect the phone to your development machine via USB and allow the connection on your machine and on the device.

For Android, if you have Android Studio and the command line tools installed, you can check if the device is connected by running `adb devices`. If your device is listed, you can then do `flutter install` on the command line at the root of your project, and the Flutter SDK will build the `.apk` file and install it on the device in one step, e.g.:

```
flutter install
Installing app-release.apk to STK LX1...
Uninstalling old version...
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk...        11.4s
```

Answer (score 0):

compile your app, then on your phone go to settings, apps & notifications, advanced, special app access, then install unknown apps. from there transfer your compiled app to your phone's downloads folder. you should be able to find it on the "show all apps" area, if you don't then open the app in the folder you transferred it to

Comment: Was able to compile and build as per the steps given by Ravindra and transfer the file to my device and install. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a USB cable you should be able to use USB debugging & android studio to setup a development server.

See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuLdD7oyML8

---

Otherwise as compile your application on your computer and file transfer it to your phone and install it as a normal APK.

Comment: I was able to compile the application on computer and was able to transfer and install on my device successfully. Thanks for your help.