# Flutter App running on emulator but not installing on real device its going till installing but stuck there

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

FlutterApp running on emulator but not installing on real device its going till installing but stuck there.
it is stuck here!

Launching lib/main.dart on V2043 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...

It's stuck here not going forward

Comment: Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69012068/13997210) hope it's helpful to you.

Comment: I did every step. Flutter clean, gradlew clean flutter upgrade even uninstall for all user in device but not run. When I install it it show installing APK in console and only white screen appear in device and nothing happens not going forward stuck there. But when I use flutter run it run succesfully