# Flutter: APK does not open the app when installed on device

Tags: android, flutter, apk, flutter-build

I've build the apk file for the app I'm working on with the command `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`. It worked without any warnings.

However, when I try to install the app on my phone, it doesn't open. I get a message saying the app has been installed correctly and I even see the app with its custom icon, but when I go to open it it doesn't work.

This is my `build.gradle`, in case that's helpful

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "<ID>"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Edit: I deleted my build with `flutter clean` and when I build the apk again I got the following errors.

```
Building with sound null safety 

Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-2.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\pathprovider\PathProviderPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-2.5.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\streamhandler\TransactionStreamHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\printing-5.6.0\android\src\main\java\net\nfet\flutter\printing\PrintingPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.       
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
```

Comment: try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69012068/13997210) hope its helpful to you

Comment: I tried it, but when I installed the app I got a message saying "App not installed"

Comment: Can you tell me you can set internet permission if you used online functionality like get and post data?

Comment: I'm using firebase..

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running the app in the release mode?

To run the app in the release mode, try this-

```
flutter run --release
```

This way, you'd be able to see what bugs are being triggered at the runtime and debug accordingly.

To the best of my knowledge, I believe it MAY HAVE something to do with the proguard rules.

Comment: What's the bug you're encountering when running in the release mode?

Comment: Also, try to build your app with this command, if it would have anything to do with proguard rules, this command would work. flutter build apk --release --split-per-abi --no-shrink

Comment: You tried the no shrink command?

Comment: And was the app working normally when in debug mode?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238683/discussion-between-gberga-and-madhavam-pratap-shahi).

Comment: I've tried downgrading flutter but that does not seem to help

Comment: Oh, well it's strange. Just build a new project, and copy the code, maybe that'd work.

Comment: Or, just debug step by step. For example, run the pp i the release mode on your device, omit some code(tht runs on the startup), and work your way up. That's the only way now.

Comment: I'll try, thanks